# timed out, nothing received

Tags: debian, ntp

I tried all and googled a lot! But I can't make work NTP on my server. This post is last hope!
I have installed **ntp** on debian server with this configuration (`/etc/ntp.conf`):

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

statdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

server 0.it.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.it.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.it.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.it.pool.ntp.org iburst

restrict -4 default nomodify nopeer noquery notrap
restrict -6 default nomodify nopeer noquery notrap

# Restrict eth0 ip
restrict 192.168.1.1
restrict 127.0.0.1 noserve nomodify
restrict ::1
```

Now when I try:

```
ntpq -pn
127.0.0.1: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

When I try:

```
ntpdate -q
9 Mar 18:08:01 ntpdate[27896]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

But with:

```
ntpdate -d 0.it.pool.ntp.org
```

I recieve incoming packets and set time offset. This lead me to wrong **ntp.conf** configuration.

Any clues why this is happening.

Comment: What file are you showing? Is that `/etc/ntp.conf`? Are you sure about those NTP servers? Try Debian's, my (working) ntp.conf [is here](http://pastebin.com/k08Ww9x8).

Comment: Yes, it's ntp.conf. I'll try with debian's servers. Thanks

Comment: Nope, always same errors.

Comment: Assuming you restarted ntpd after making these changes, is that correct? `service ntpd restart`.

Comment: What is your firewall configuration? Are you sure that there isn't a firewall in between that's blocking NTP?

Comment: @slm Ofcourse, but the error persists.

Comment: @Gilles I'm not sure how can check if something is blocking NTP, or is already user port 123.

Comment: Ok, i checked firewall, and added:

     iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
     iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT

Comment: @BojanVidanovic `sudo lsof -i:123` and `sudo iptables -L`

Comment: @BojanVidanovic check syslog & daemon log, see if you're getting any errors from ntpd.

Comment: Also, your restrict lines are weird... Look at http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions

Comment: @derobert No errors in log files, that's the beauty.

Comment: @derobert Actually in daemon.log there is line: peers refreshed. No errors, seems like it's working but i get error with ntpq -pn.

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  One server will only return the timeout error with ntpq -p; manually running ntpdate -s succeeds though.  Other servers (all running Ubuntu Server 13.10) have no issue--and all debugging steps I've found on this thread and others leave me without an explanation or obvious problem

Answer (score 3):

If none of the NTP servers you're trying seem to be responding, it's likely that a firewall is blocking either outgoing requests or incoming responses.

NTP uses UDP port 123. You can check whether outgoing requests are being blocked by running traceroute on that port. Depending on your implementation of traceroute, this may be something like `traceroute -p 123 0.it.pool.ntp.org` (Debian includes several implementations of traceroute, check `traceroute --help` or `man traceroute` on your system). If incoming requests are blocked but outgoing requests get through, I don't think you can diagnose where they are blocked without access to a machine outside your network (if you have access to such a machine, run `traceroute -p 123 your.ip.address`). Note that if you have a [private IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address#Private_networks), being able to use NTP requires the cooperation of your network administrator (specifically, NTP support in the [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) appliance).

If you've set up a firewall on your machine, make sure it's letting NTP through. The simple way is to allow all traffic on UDP port 123:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 123 --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 123 --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

(You may want to add `-d`/`-s` directives to restrict to a particular IP address or set of IP addresses. Note that if you do that, you'll need to update these rules if the NTP servers in the pool you're using change IP addresses.)

If NTP traffic is blocked somewhere between your machine and the Internet, contact your network administrator. It's likely that there is a relay machine that you can use as your NTP server.

Comment: External NTP traffic is likely being blocked by your hosting provider /ISP. This is a heavy handed approach to prevent DDOS. Ask your ISP what internal ntp servers you can connect to.

Comment: @dfc In my experience, corporate firewalls block NTP as part of blocking all UDP or as a natural consequence of NAT, but ISPs don't (except the ones who NAT). But indeed, if your ISP blocks incoming NTP, they *should* provide an NTP server on their network.

Comment: I had already added these rules to iptables, but still same error. Strangly with: ntpdate -d 0.it.pool.ntp.org, it works. So i belive it's ntp.conf.

Comment: @Gilles is "your experience" taking into consideration the recent wave of DDoS attacks that use ntp? A year ago I would agree with your comment. However after the recent waves of attacks egress ntp filtering is a lot more common than you think.

Comment: @BojanVidanovic It does not make any sense that it works with ntpdate and not with ntp. When it works with ntpdate you should make note of the IP address that returned ann answer and try putting that into ntp.conf. The DNS response for pool.ntp.org address will vary depending on how many servers the pool monitor thingks are currently healthy in addition to some pseudo randomization in the dns daemon.

Comment: @Gilles add this to the experience pile: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429306/ntpdate-no-server-suitable-for-synchronization-found

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell your question is "Why does `ntpq -pn` not function as I expect it to?"

Change this line:

```
restrict 127.0.0.1 noserve nomodify
```

back to what it was originally:

```
restrict 127.0.0.1
```

now `ntpq -pn` will work.

FYI: `::1` is the IPv6 version of `127.0.0.1`

Updated config:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

statdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

server 0.it.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.it.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.it.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.it.pool.ntp.org iburst

restrict -4 default nomodify nopeer noquery notrap
restrict -6 default nomodify nopeer noquery notrap

# Restrict eth0 ip
restrict 192.168.1.1
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out

Comment: You updated your /etc/ntp.conf to what is shown above and resstarted ntp and you got the timed out message? what is the output of `netstat -laun` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have also added "restrict localhost" at the end of restrictions

Answer (score 1):

Your issue appears to be in the selection of those 2 servers in these 2 lines of your config file:

```
server ntp1.inrim.it iburst
server ntp2.inrim.it iburst
```

When I try to query either of them I get your error as well:

```
$ sudo ntpq -p ntp1.inrim.it
ntp1.inrim.it: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out

$ sudo ntpq -p ntp2.inrim.it
ntp2.inrim.it: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

I'd try selecting some different servers for starters.

#### Those servers?

When I google for their names I came across this page titled: [Come configurare il vostro NTP](http://www.inrim.it/ntp/config_i.shtml). There was another server that didn't work mentioned there either:

```
$ sudo ntpq -p host2.miaditta.it 
host2.miaditta.it: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

These servers would seem to be the issue.

#### Encryption?

If you look further down that URL above that I mentioned, they discuss using encryption, you might need to enable this to access those NTP servers.

#### Debugging tips

I was able to successfully connect to both of your `iburst` servers using this command:

```
$ ntpdate -d <server>
```

*Example*

```
$ ntpdate -d ntp1.inrim.it
 9 Mar 21:01:37 ntpdate[20739]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Tue Apr  2 17:47:01 UTC 2013 (1)
Looking for host ntp1.inrim.it and service ntp
host found : ntp1.inrim.it
transmit(193.204.114.232)
receive(193.204.114.232)
...
server 193.204.114.232, port 123
stratum 1, precision -22, leap 00, trust 000
refid [CTD], delay 0.19319, dispersion 0.00084
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    d6c78d79.f0206119  Sun, Mar  9 2014 21:01:45.937
originate timestamp: d6c78d7e.55ab5b4b  Sun, Mar  9 2014 21:01:50.334
transmit timestamp:  d6c78d77.7e9b8296  Sun, Mar  9 2014 21:01:43.494
filter delay:  0.19460  0.19710  0.19453  0.19319 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 6.755368 6.757349 6.755239 6.756265
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.19319, dispersion 0.00084
offset 6.756265

 9 Mar 21:01:43 ntpdate[20739]: step time server 193.204.114.232 offset 6.756265 sec
```

So it would seem your issue is actually something wrong with your `ntp.conf` file. Please confirm this is the case and we can continue debugging further.

Comment: Yes i won't use those servers, but i added debian.pool.ntp.org, and i still get: timed out. Or it.pool.ntp.org, which works give me the same error. At this point i think something is blocking NTP.

Comment: if i try: ntpdate 0.debian.pool.ntp.org, it works.

Comment: Yes, with: ntpdate -d ntp1.inrim.it i see same results as yours. Then probably it's ntp.conf.

Comment: @BojanVidanovic - yes yes, the issue is likely your `ntp.conf` then. So this is good progress. I'd take out the most of the lines except for the server ones to debug this further.

Comment: I updated my question with current configuration.

Comment: @BojanVidanovic - I just dropped the above file you posted into my Fedora 19 system and it worked fine. Did you start the service? `service ntpd restart`?

Comment: Yep, i do that all the time. Just for me it's: service ntp restart (not ntpd). That's really strange, i even added rules to iptables..

Comment: @BojanVidanovic - does the `/var/log/syslog` show anything about it? You might want to enable verbose messaging in /etc/ntp.conf` for more info.

Comment: Just checked, no ntp errors related. No i'll try enabling verbose messaging.

Comment: The switches to `ntpd`, adding `-d` options will add more, and `-D level` will enable INFO, TRACE, DEBUG, etc.

Comment: When i run ntpq -pn In daemon.log file i get: peers refreshed.

Comment: Might be helpful to go through this checklist: http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/debug.html

Comment: @slm  The command `ntpq -p ntp1.inrim.it` does not do what you think it does. that command asks the server for a list of its configured peers/timesources. It does not ask the remote server for the time. You can have a "perfectly functioning" public time server that serves time to clients but does not respond to remote peer requests. It is also known as noquery in the restric line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the loopback adapter was disabled in system. After enabling it, problem was solved. See /etc/network/interfaces file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you have configured an NTP SERVER but you are pointing that to a POOL

```
server 0.pool.ntp.org
```

Try:

```
pool 0.pool.ntp.org
```

instead or use "server" with a dedicated server, not a pool.